# How to improve page load time with any pre rendering approach?

Tags: dd4t, 9.6

we are using SDL Tridion sites 9.6 with DD4T 2.0 framework. we got some requirement from our SEO agency like rendering website page data faster through server-side rendering process. Presently we are rendering all the page components in one shot. Can anyone please share best ways to improve website page performance or any supporting prerendering options to load page initially with first two components and later we can load other components.

Any suggestion is of great help. Thanks!

Comment: This is not a tridion question. This is something to review your implementation and caching strategy.  we had a similar requirement using this https://pagespeed.web.dev/ lighthouse report to suggest improving the performance of the pages for SEO. worth looking into this.

Comment: I think the question is specifically about page rendering times on the server, so I would say it is definitely Tridion/DD4T/CIL related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to give concrete advice without knowing your solution.

Generally, there are different ways to improve page rendering performance in a DD4T implementation:

- use DD4T object caching
- Output caching
- Optimize your own code with performance in mind

You could also take a look at Dyndle, a framework built on top of DD4T which comes (among many other things) with output caching with automatic decaching when a page is published. See for example https://www.dyndle.com/docs/caching.html.